# I need help setting my password in a distrobox container

Tags: command-line, sudo, tools

For some reason my other post got downvoted and no replies so I'll try again. I set up a distrobox container for ubuntu 23.04. However, I cannot set the password and therefore cannot run and sudo commands. Here's how I set up and entered the container. The user password does not get inherited from the host system. I think the issue might be here

```
 Warning: there was a problem setting up the user
 Warning: trying manual addition [ OK ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
(deck@steamdeck ~)$ distrobox create --image ubuntu:23.04 --name ubuntu
Creating 'ubuntu' using image ubuntu:23.04       [ OK ]
Distrobox 'ubuntu' successfully created.
To enter, run:

distrobox enter ubuntu

(deck@steamdeck ~)$ distrobox enter ubuntu
Container ubuntu is not running.
Starting container ubuntu
run this command to follow along:

 podman logs -f ubuntu

 Starting container...                           [ OK ]
 Installing basic packages...                    [ OK ]
 Setting up read-only mounts...                  [ OK ]
 Setting up read-write mounts...                 [ OK ]
 Setting up host's sockets integration...        [ OK ]
 Integrating host's themes, icons, fonts...      [ OK ]
 Setting up package manager exceptions...        [ OK ]
 Setting up dpkg exceptions...                   [ OK ]
 Setting up apt hooks...                         [ OK ]
 Setting up sudo...                              [ OK ]
 Setting up groups...                            [ OK ]
 Integrating host's themes, icons, fonts...      [ OK ]
 Setting up package manager exceptions...        [ OK ]
 Setting up dpkg exceptions...                   [ OK ]
 Setting up apt hooks...                         [ OK ]
 Setting up sudo...                              [ OK ]
 Setting up groups...                            [ OK ]
 Setting up users...                    
 Warning: there was a problem setting up the user
 Warning: trying manual addition [ OK ]
 Executing init hooks...                         [ OK ]

Container Setup Complete!
bash: xhost: command not found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
```

Comment: I closed the other one. Delete it if you want :)

Comment: What happens if you run `passwd`?

Comment: Passwords vary depending on which Ubuntu ISO you're talking about; and you're using an image from a non-Ubuntu source without specifics as to which they're using. Passwords can be *null* (just hit enter), *undefined* (*being set at install & its invalid until then, but won't be needed until after install when Ubuntu ISO is run*) or 'ubuntu', or maybe other alternatives given there are >15 Ubuntu 23.04 ISO/images (across products, architectures, cloud variations etc)